# node typescript client-side debug

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-debugging

Is is possible to debug (breakpoints, watches) **client-side** .ts typescript files **from visual studio (2015) directly**? Most of the related issues that I have found on google and stackoverflow suggest using other browser devtools such as chrome. Is it possible to do it in visual studio?

When I create a .ts script (say index.ts), it will be transpiled into a index.js which will then be referenced from the corresponding index.html file in the script tag.

How can I set breakpoints in the .ts file (although it is the .js which is referenced?)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with IE. You have to set "Browse with" to Internet Explorer and in the project properties/web unchecked all debuggers. Than you should be able to debug client-side TS in VS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. in the project properties I cannot see the web tab where to uncheck all debuggers. This is a node.js project using the lates NVTS (node visual studio tools). I just have a "General" tab with options such as Node.exe.path, launch url ...etc. Is there something I should do to see the web tab?

Comment: I realize that as soon as a launch my debug session (pressing the green arrow with the name of the browser used to debug - here ie), this button is then disabled. Thus I can no more access the option "Browse with". And if I only press "Browse with", a browser window starts but cannot show any content because my node.js app server is not running yet...Have you really been able to debug node.js server + client-side .ts files in visual studio?

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t know, that´s Node js project. I was able to debug client-side TS in  C# project. But I thing it should be possible in Node.js project too, maybe you should create Windows Azure Node js project, where are web.configs files. I can try it later.

Comment: I cannot create windows azure as we will host it on premices. thanks any way for your help

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can debug in visual studio but launching a a new debug session from internet explorer: menu->view->external script debugger which will start a new visual studio ide with all my files (.js and .ts mapped) loaded. I just have to make sure that the .js and .ts files are in the same directory (example: ./public/js/ ). It is not a perfect solution (for example bringing the cursor over a variable does not show the variable value. You must manually open the watch window...) But it allows me to step through my .ts files thus keeping a unified development environment: typescript with node.js on the server, typescript on the client-side within the same solution

Answer (score 0):

You might try with this *HTML Application with TypeScript* project template from [Web Essentials 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee6e6d8c-c837-41fb-886a-6b50ae2d06a2) extension, as suggested in [this post](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/typescript-with-visual-studio-2015/) from Telerik blog.

If that works, it seems just a matter of usual VS scenario "set breakpoint; hit F5".